# Android GCM, retrieve reg_id from google ? is possible?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Does anyone knows, how I can retrieve the Reg_id (registration id) from the Google Cloud Messaging about the devices registered ? my colleague have accidentally delete our database and our provider does not have backups ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's unfortunate. There is no API to retrieve the list of Registration IDs of devices registered for GCM by your app. However, if your app sends the registration ID to your server each time it launches, you would be able to reconstruct your DB over time. If not, you can make an update to your app to make it send the Registration ID to your server whenever it is launched, which would at least give you the Registration IDs of devices that get the updated version.